# How to Plot Data Using matplotlib, pandas and tkinter Python (AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'scan_area')

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a python code in which I attempt to read a csv file using **askopenfilename** to grab the file name and then use **pandas** to pull the data. During testing the code without the addition of **askopenfilename** it was able to plot the data however, it is now unable to display the plot at all. Any idea as to what has happened to cause this error?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


file_name = askopenfilename()

df = pd.read_csv(file_name)

print(df)

scan = df.scan_area   # this is where the AttributeError is flagged
X = df.x_coor
Y = df.y_coor
Z = df.thickness

previous_scan_unit = df.units[1]
previous_scan_name = df.scan_area[1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')       

ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, cmap='RdYlGn')#, edgecolors='grey', alpha=0.5)

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='black')

ax.set_title('Data Collected from Scan ' + previous_scan_name)
ax.set_xlabel('Transducer Displacement (' + previous_scan_unit +')')
ax.set_ylabel('Machine Displacement (' + previous_scan_unit +')')
ax.set_zlabel('Material Thickness (' + previous_scan_unit +')')

plt.show()
```

As marked with a comment in the above code there is an error on **scan = df.scan_area** however, the **print(df)** above displays the data correctly seen below along with the error (DEPRECATION WARNING is due to use of an OSX version of Tk):

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
   scan area  voltage  gate start  gate width  x coor  y coor  voltage.1  thickness units
0     test 1        1         0.5        0.25     0.0     0.0        0.5       0.25    mm
1     test 1        1         0.5        0.25     0.5     0.0        0.6       0.25    mm
2     test 1        1         0.5        0.25     1.0     0.0        0.7       0.25    mm
3     test 1        1         0.5        0.25     1.5     0.0        0.5       0.25    mm
4     test 1        1         0.5        0.25     0.0     0.5        0.5       0.25    mm
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/Capstone/testplotter.py", line 13, in <module>
    scan = df.scan_area   # df is the variable name and .scan_area is the column header 
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/Capstone/venv_capstone/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5462, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'scan_area'
```

Comment: Compare `scan_area` and `scan area`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column is called "scan area" but you are trying to access "scan_area". You should instead access the column with `scan = df["scan area"]`. You will need to do something similar with "x coor" and "y coor".